# Use debounce inside a custom React hook for input change

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-hooks, debouncing

I have a custom hook `useForm`, which stores form values and validates input values.

```
const { errors, handleChange, values } = useForm();
```

`handleChange` validates on every input change. Is it possible to use debouce inside a custom hook? If yes, how to do it?

```
const handleChange = (ev) => {
  ev.persist();

  // set value in values state
  const currentError = validate(/* pass params */)
  // update errors state
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `debounce` from libraries such as `lodash/underscore` or write your own debounce function. Post that you need to debounce your handleChange function and make use of `useCallback` so that you aren't creating a new debounce function on each render

```
const handleChange = useCallback(_.debounce((ev) => {
  ev.persist();

  // set value in values state
  const currentError = validate(/* pass params */)
  // update errors state
}, 500), []);
```

Also when you use useCallback and ensure that the function in created only initially. Its better to not depend on the variables from the enclosing lexical scope.

Comment: Great, useCallback hook is the right solution to avoid recreating debounce function.

Answer (score 2):

You can also validate the values onBlur instead of onChange. Validation will triggered once and you won't need to debounce it.

Comment: This is more suited as a comment.

Comment: I do agree, but I couldn't make one, because -> "You must have 50 reputation to comment" :D

Comment: I understand but adding inefficient answers will get you downvotes hence causing you more damage. Please wait patiently, you will have enough reputation if you add value to the community effectively! All the very best!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this by wrapping the function inside the debounce

```
const doValidation = (ev) => {
  ev.persist();

  // set value in values state
  const currentError = validate(/* pass params */)
  // update errors state
};

const handleChange = debounce(doValidation,100)
```

With this your validation should only be called once every 100ms.